# PDO Exception Symfony 2

Tags: postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

Trying to run `php app\console doctrine:schema:update --force`. I Catch this error: [image]

In parameters.ini I use `database_driver   = pdo_pgsql`

What about my phpinfo? It seems everything is alright! [image]

Can you give me advice what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason might be that CLI and Apache versions of PHP have different configuration and `pdo_pgsql` is not activated for the CLI version.

Comment: when i run this command i don't see `pdo_pgsql` what should i do.?